# Java/Android: How do you properly import a library in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I'm working on an Android project and i need to import an XML library called XOM. The only way i found was to right click on the project name -> Properties -> Libraries tab -> click on "Add external Jar". But that only references it from it's original path, what happens when i compile the app and move it to my phone? Will the Jar be in there?

Might be a stupid question, sorry if that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to do that but what I normally do is create a folder called `lib`and then add Jars from there. I find that makes it easier to see what Jars I have in my application.

The main disadvantage of your original approach is that what if the path to that library externally accidentally changes? then your program will not compile. It's better to have everything in the one place to make things easier.

Comment: Agreed, but how do i move the actual Jar file to the lib folder in my project? Do i add it manually by moving the file there, or should i import it through Eclipse some how? Also, after moving it to the lib folder, can i make it so that android looks for all libraries in that folder automatically?

Comment: @qwerty You can simply drag and drop it.

Comment: Alright, that worked. But i can't import the library from anywhere, i need to reference the library from the build path, right? How do i do that?

Comment: @qwerty Right click your project. Go to `Java Build Path` > `Add JARs...` > then navigate to the `lib` folder inside your project and click on the `.jar` file.

Comment: That's what i've been doing so far, but i haven't been keeping the libraries in a /lib folder. Do i need to reference all the libraries manually, or is there any way to reference all of them by just pointing at the /lib folder?

Comment: @qwerty You have to reference them all manually from the lib folder. Make sure to remove the references to the ones external to the lib folder before re-referencing the same libraries in the lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

`.apk` is nothing but a collection or zipped version of a file. it contains all the resources and compiled java files.
So you need not have to worry about the inclusion of your library files. if you have set proper path to your libraries in eclipse then these will be included in your apk file.

Comment: Alright, but just for developments sake, it would be better to have my libraries in a /lib folder in my project, right? How do i set a path to the /lib folder so that it looks for everything within when i compile the project?

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory called "libs" in your under your root directory. You can do it by,

- Right click on the project which is in the Package Explorer window in
  Eclipse.
- New -> Folder -> give "libs" as the Folder name
- Copy your jar file and paste it to in the "libs" folder
- Expand the "libs" folder
- Right click on your copied jar file -> Build Path -> Add to build
  path

That's it

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, i still need to go in to the properties and add it manually afterwards for it to work. But it probably should work, i' not sure why it's not. Thanks though!